# What is the name of the side-turn defense in Capoeira?

Tags: terminology, capoeira

It's the motion at the 3 second to 4 second mark [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYEoE-qqvaU) where the *capoeiristra* pivots so that their side faces their opponent and they're sitting back a bit. It's often done before a [*Queixada*](http://www.akban.org/wiki/Queixada), particularly since it works well for a partner drill where *capoeiristras* trade kicks, using this defense to avoid the incoming kick while setting up for the next, but I've also seen it suggested as a defense against a *Bênção* or *Chapa* (moving back from the attack while potentially moving to the side of it) or against a more lateral attack by turning your back to it, either catching the kick along the flat of the back to reduce its force (and because the back is not a valid target in the *roda*, thus negating the hit) or to facilitate ducking under it.

The description in the above-linked article is:

> From the base position of the ginga, with one leg pointed backward, shift the chest in an orthogonal line to the opponent, turning on the two feet; bend the legs at the knee, sitting on the pelvis (a straight leg can be an easy target, and it hurts bad).

When stepping into the movement, I've often seen it described as *[Entrada](http://gatorato.com/video/capoeira-moves-entrada/)*. When I was studying in Philadelphia, Mestre Doutor had a name for it, which I think might have rhymed with "*Queixada*" because I remember him prompting the moves and I remember the two going together, which could match with it being *Entrada* other than that sounds backwards since you're retreating, not entering.

Ah, and I have found one pictorial reference. It's the first two steps, here depicted as the setup for a *Queixada* courtesy of [this site](https://www.virtualcapoeira.com/basics.htm):
[image: Queixada]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to get ahold of my instructor from Philadelphia, but I did get an answer from one of his senior assistants who said that they always just taught that pivot as the wind-up for the *queixada* and that there was no distinct name for it.

> Yes, it's queixada. It's strange to read the technical description. [The] esquiva is part of the queixada. The textbook doesn't do it justice. I need to see it.

I have since found a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/lD-F7fIhkTs) which refers to this movement as *quebrada* ("ravine"), which matches the rhyming scheme I remember. What may have been throwing me off is that it involves a more bent position than the example images I provided above.

For what it is worth, my Angola instructor refers to this as *esquiva atrás*, or "dodge behind", although that does include the backwards dodging aspect rather than just turning for the kick.

Answer (score 5):

Esquiva part of Queixada is called "Finta de Queixada".

Queixada is a two stages capoeira kick :
- First we do a "esquiva de lado"
- Then we do the kick

But if you're only doing the "esquiva de lado" part of the Queixada, you are not trying to do an **esquiva** but a **finta** (making one thinking you're about to do the kick, but transform and do something else).

That's why this movement is called "Finta de Queixada".

Answer (score 3):

The name is "*[Esquiva de lado](http://www.akban.org/wiki/Esquiva_de_lado)*" ("Sideways esquiva"). It can be used as part of the *entrada*.

Personally I'd call the steps after the *esquiva* the *entrada* (picture 3 in your sequence) because there are other ways to get to the steps if you enter after a *finta*.

For a reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuBW3Qp9YHQ